# Any gem for designing a blog post in Rails with syntax highlighting and inline image attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-highlighting, blogs

I am trying to make a personal blog in Ruby on Rails. I want to design individual **post** with syntax highlighting as well as inline multiple **image attachment**. I have tried `ckeditor` gem with paperclip but the syntax highlighting doesn't work with [redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) and [pygments.rb](https://github.com/tmm1/pygments.rb).

I am looking to create the blog post something similar to [this](http://cloudinary.com/blog/ruby_on_rails_and_cloudinary_image_management_for_an_amazing_web_dev_framework).Please help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Obtvse](https://github.com/natew/obtvse2), an open source blog engine inspired by [Svbtle](https://svbtle.com/) does pretty much exactly what you are looking for.

It uses [Coderay](http://coderay.rubychan.de/) for syntax highlighting which is a pure ruby library and does not depend on javascript, and [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) (through [Kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/)) for editing posts rather than a WYSIWYG solution like CKEDITOR which IMHO is a more sane choice - especially for technically inclined.

Backend based syntax highlighting plays well with RSS readers as opposed to javascript based solutions.

You can either use the application and customize as per your requirements, or take a look at the implementation and use that to build your own solution.

Alternatively if you are specifically inclined towards using CKEditor you might want to take a look at [this plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/codemirror) which integrates CKEditor with [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/), which is among the most popular solutions for code editing and highlighting in javascript. For displaying the snippets you can also use CodeMirror in a readonly mode as described in this [manual](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html). This will ensure that you get the exact same syntax highlighting while editing as well in post view page.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer, this is what I was looking for. Will try the CodeMirror solution.

Comment: I tried to use the CodeMirror plugin with CKeditor gem. Somehow I am not able to use CodeMirror. I have extracted the CodeMirror files in to the public folder and done the required configuration in the config.js of the CKeditor. Can you please guide me how to configure it?

Comment: Will it be possible for you to share the code through github - (perhaps a bare rails repo with just the codemirror related additions) so I can reproduce the problem easily ?

Answer (score 3):

I like to use prismjs for syntax highlighting -> http://prismjs.com

As I was learning about rails engine and use prismjs for multiple rails app, I pack prismjs into a rubygem ([highlighting](https://rubygems.org/gems/highlighting)) for my own convenience.

**To setup prismjs in rails**, add `gem 'highlighting'` to your gemfile.

Next, add `//= require prism` and `//= require prism-[language]` at application.js like below:

```
//= require turbolink
//= require prism 
//= require prism-[language]
```

replace [language] with the name of language. For example: `prism-ruby` or `prism-coffeescript`

At application.css, add `*= require prism-[theme]` or use the default `*= require prism`

```
*= require prism
```

There are various other themes to choose from. For example `*= require prism-tomorrow`, `*= require prism-twilight`.

**To use them in your view**, do this:

```
<pre>
<code class="language-ruby">
   <!-- type any ruby code you like --> 
</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how to add inline image attachment with it? Have you tested it with ckeditor?

Comment: You should go with what lorefnon suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax highlighting is usually done via javascript, for example via [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/)

Also for a programmer's personal blog there are more specialized solutions like `jekyll` (which powers github pages)

Comment: Thanks @vasfed well I am learning ROR and was looking to build the blog on the same as my first project as well as learning the same. Can you throw more light on exactly how can I achieve it?

Comment: Then you can use ckeditor with plugin for `code` tag and then highlight all code tags on client via js, other option is the same, but you'll need to parse ckeditor-generated html to replace content inside code tags with highlighed version