# Handling user inputted code - security

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app allows users to enter code from any language(python, c, java, ruby, etc), and I use [PrismJS](http://prismjs.com/) as a syntax highlighter. Does rails handle xss and injections, or do I need to further sanitize/validate the code?

What is the correct way to securely handle user inputted code (like stackoverflow)?

#### Form Input

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Code Snippet</label>
  <%= f.text_area :body, class: "end-field form-control", placeholder: "", rows: 8 %>
</div>
```

#### View

```
<pre><code class="language-<%= snippet.language %> line-numbers"><%= snippet.body %></code></pre>
```

Currently not doing any sanitiation or validation.

#### Output:

[image]

Comment: A related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162236/any-gem-for-designing-a-blog-post-in-rails-with-syntax-highlighting-and-inline-i) suggests using [coderay](http://coderay.rubychan.de/)

Comment: @ImranAli I came across the same post. But coderay seems out of date and supports a limited number of languages (compared to PrismJS).

Comment: how about [google prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify)?

Comment: Show us the related controller code. I suspect it's secure, but would need to see the controller saving to the database to be sure.

Comment: @ScottS. it is just being saved normally as the form is submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OWASP (XXS prevention cheat sheet, Rule #1)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.231_-_HTML_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Element_Content) recommends that you sanitize the code between two tags by using the following replacements:

```
 & --> &amp;
 < --> &lt;
 > --> &gt;
 " --> &quot;
 ' --> &#x27;     &apos; not recommended because its not in the HTML spec (See: section 24.4.1) &apos; is in the XML and XHTML specs.
 / --> &#x2F;     forward slash is included as it helps end an HTML entity
```

Here is what they say:

> Rule #1 is for when you want to put untrusted data directly into the
>   HTML body somewhere. This includes inside normal tags like div, p, b,
>   td, etc. Most web frameworks have a method for HTML escaping for the
>   characters detailed below. However, this is absolutely not sufficient
>   for other HTML contexts. You need to implement the other rules
>   detailed here as well.
>
> ```
> `<body>...ESCAPE UNTRUSTED DATA BEFORE PUTTING HERE...</body>`   
> `<div>...ESCAPE UNTRUSTED DATA BEFORE PUTTING HERE...</div>`
>
> any other normal HTML elements
> ```
>
> Escape the following characters with HTML
>   entity encoding to prevent switching into any execution context, such
>   as script, style, or event handlers. Using hex entities is recommended
>   in the spec. In addition to the 5 characters significant in XML (&, <, >, ", '), the forward slash is included as it helps to end an HTML entity.
>
> ```
> & --> &amp;
> < --> &lt;
> > --> &gt;
> " --> &quot;
> ' --> &#x27;     &apos; not recommended because its not in the HTML spec (See: section 24.4.1) &apos; is in the XML and XHTML specs.
> / --> &#x2F;     forward slash is included as it helps end an HTML entity
> ```
>
> See the [ESAPI reference implementation](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/codecs/HTMLEntityCodec.java) of HTML entity escaping and unescaping.
>
> ```
> String safe = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML( request.getParameter("input" ) );
> ```

**My Sample Implementation (NOT DEFINITELY SAFE)**

```
def sanitize_inside_tags(text)
    {"&"=>"amp",
     "<"=>"lt",
     ">"=>"gt",
     "\""=>"quot",
     "'"=>"#x27",
     "/"=>"#x2F"}.each do |char,replacement|
        text = text.gsub(char,"&#{replacement};")
    end
    return text
end
```

**Rails Sanitize Method**

This would probably be the best option for you, because is not only a well used and tested sanitation library, but it also allows some tags, such as `<b>` and friends so that your users can actually use some html markup safely.

In answer to your question, YES, you can use the rails sanitation library safely and it is probably the right choice in your situation.

If you want to strip all tags or allow less you can look into custimization [here](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer/blob/master/README.md).

**Syntax Hilighting**

As @ImranAli suggested in his comment, look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162236/any-gem-for-designing-a-blog-post-in-rails-with-syntax-highlighting-and-inline-i) and try to look at all the libraries listed.

Comment: The answer you gave gives examples on html escaping. But is there a feasible way to implement escaping for all languages? I currently have inputs from over 50 languages. Do I need to go through every tag scenario for each language?

Comment: The only thjng you need to sanitize are things that would interfere with your html document. Your browser won't just detect and run code in an arbitrary language in a html page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sanitize` method from `ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper` module.

```
<pre>
  <code class="language-<%= snippet.language %> line-numbers">
  <%= sanitize(snippet.body) %></code>
</pre>
```

Note: I indented your code just for better looking. You should use without indentations.

For more information: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize

Comment: This does not work. For example, if a user inputs html code such as `<script src="js/timedropper.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/timedropper.css">`, the entire code snippet gets sanitized.

Comment: I provided a link to get more details about how it works. There are some options to customize it. If you look at the "examples" section, you will see how you can use a custom scrubber. There are two options [Rails HTML Sanitizer](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer) or [Loofah](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah). There are tons of options to customize them.